# Create FeatureLayer from scratch

Tags: python, arcgis, esri

I'm trying to create new instance of [arcgis.features.FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#featurelayer) using python arcgis package.

I find it impossible, I'm traversing through [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference) and [examples](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/appending-features/#Append-attribute-values-from-the-csv-item-into-target-feature-layer-attribute-field) and [more examples](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/blob/master/samples/05_content_publishers/publishing_sd_shapefiles_and_csv.ipynb), trying different things and I find myself going round in circles and slowly I start pulling my hear out...

This is what I have:

```py
import arcgis
import json
from arcgis.gis import GIS

g = GIS(username="my_uname", password="my_pwd")
prop = arcgis.features.FeatureCollection(dictdata={'attributes': {'foo': 'bar', 'lorem': 'ipsum'}})
prop_json=json.dumps({"featureCollection": {"layers": [dict(prop.properties)]}})
item_properties={"type": "Feature Collection", "title": "test_feature_collection_01", "text": prop_json}
it = g.content.add(item_properties=item_properties)
```

At this point - I can't understand why `it.layers` yields empty results. I believe `item_properties` is malformed resulting in `arcgis` ignoring my layers definition... but I have nowhere to check what it should look like. I figured I'd like to use something from `arcgis` to generate layer definition for me rather than to handcraft JSON myself so it's future-proof.

What I want to do with that item later is this:

```py
lr = arcgis.features.FeatureLayer.fromitem(item=it)
```

This fails with `TypeError: item must be a type of service, not Feature Collection`

So I figured I could publish item and use it here.

```py
pit = it.publish()
lr = arcgis.features.FeatureLayer.fromitem(item=pit)
```

I need `FeatureLayer` to be able to call `append` (so I can just throw extra data each time I have anything new I want to push)

But to my surprise I cannot even publish the item and I'm getting `Exception: Job failed.` (to my bigger surprise item actually gets published as I can see it through content manager website)

I also tried creating "CSV" item type:

```py
import arcgis
import json
from arcgis.gis import GIS


g = GIS(username="my_uname", password="my_pwd")
item_properties={"type": "CSV", "title": "test_feature_collection_01"}
it = g.content.add(item_properties=item_properties, data="/tmp/foo.csv")
pit = it.publish()

lr = arcgis.features.FeatureLayer.fromitem(item=pit)
```

However this results in layer-less item, which results in unhandled exception `IndexError: list index out of range` (because method `arcgis` calls tries to get to layers which is empty...)

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get ***sort-of*** what I need... however I'm still trying to understand how to make `arcgis` to upload some data directly from my hard drive rather than from another item. Anyways here is the code:

```py
import arcgis
import json
from arcgis.gis import GIS

g = GIS(username="my_uname", password="my_pwd")

item_properties_1={"type": "CSV", "title": "test_feature_collection_01"}
it_1 = g.content.add(item_properties=item_properties_1, data="/tmp/my_data.csv")
pit_1 = it_1.publish()
table = arcgis.features.Table.fromitem(item=pit_1)

# Now we want to throw some extra data, do we have to create another item to do that??

item_properties_2={"type": "CSV", "title": "test_feature_collection_02"}
it_2 = g.content.add(item_properties=item_properties_2, data="/tmp/more_data.csv")
source_info = g.content.analyze(file_path='/tmp/more_data.csv', file_type='csv', location_type='none')

# Data from `it_2` appears to be appended to `table` container (which is published item, not item itself)

table.append(item_id=it_2.id, upload_format='csv', source_info=source_info["publishParameters"], upsert=False)
```

So to append some data to existing item I have to create new item...

---

Edit:

To upload data without having to create interim item use `edit_features` instead of `append`.

```py
# create table like shown in sample above

from arcgis import features
f = features.Feature.from_dict({"attributes": {"some_attribute": "value"}})
fs = features.FeatureSet(features=[f])
table.edit_features(adds=fs)
```